# How to build a lab at home/school? (general purpose, sophisticated, reliable and cheap)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, specific-reference, laboratory-safety

> The title includes the main objective and all the criteria; namely:
>
> **A.** A lab is to be built.
>
> **B.** It must adhere to the following criteria:
>
> 1. ***Reasonably cheap*** for a limited-fund school/limited budget home. Eg. **\$5000** for a **school**, *\$2000* for a *house*.
> 2. ***General purpose*** for high-school material. Presumably including all that's needed for earlier school years as well. -The same level (that of high-school material) should be enough for a house-lab.
> 3. ***Reliable*** with long life expectancy under light/controlled/correct use. With all the safety tools included.
> 4. ***Sophisticated*** in that it's more or less like garage labs seen in films where villains make nuclear bombs in basements. *(Take that with a jar of salt :) )*

- Needed are a list of tools and basic materials that need to be included (chemicals, microscopes, etc...)
- The list *should **not*** include basic structures like taps, tables, ventilation, wardrobes, etc... or the cost of workmanship needed to install and prepare everything.
- Mention a reason why something needs to be included like allowing people to monitor the skies (telescopes) and so on.

  - What conditions would be optimal for each case? A clear sky is needed for a telescope ass well as a good location for monitoring. Maybe an ambient temp. of 27C is best for chemistry related tests and demonstrations? Etc...
- Assume three (3) persons will be using the lab at any given time.
- *(High-school material)* means (in a grand generalization):

  1. Strictly 'Biology subjects' are not included. So no plates for dissection, etc... /Scissors and so on should be included for other purposes<sup>confirmation needed</sup>.
  2. Tools for -Classical Mechanics, -Electricity and -Basic Elemental Chemistry should be included.

Please don't suggest specific brands but rather the tools themselves with a simple link to a description. Specific tools in markets could be mentioned after their common name is mentioned (the name of the tool alone.).

Thank you for your support and please note that there're people out there who are better than me in language; if you are, please<sup>**99**</sup> help me tidy up the question! I also need help with the tags; the current ones seem inappropriate and insufficient.

Comment: I would like the advice from people with experience in this. Please don't link to general articles that assume a home in Europe or the US. Rather, stick to international side so the question could be most useful. Add hints about the middle-east specifically if you want to help with my particular case locally.

Comment: Labs are built with a goal in mind, not for the sake of building one. Think of something you would like to build and join a science club.

Comment: Stack Exchange is generally [very negative on make-a-list questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), which is how I am interpreting this. We *have* made exception on Physics.SE for books and paper requests (which is [what the reference-request tag is for](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info)), but I don't see this a fitting into that niche. Further exceptions would be made by opening a topic on meta and collecting a consensus from the user base.

Comment: Agreed, I believe this is far too broad a question to be appropriate for Stack Exchange.